# Append HTML except particular class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-append

On click checkbox appending `#mosaic` HTML to `#assetSelectedList` but want to skip `.asset-paid-li` class to append.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/s39ycu18/6/)**

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
  if (this.checked) {
    $("ul#assetSelectedList").append($("ul#mosaic").html());
    $('ul#assetSelectedList input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  }
  else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing1">
<ul id="mosaic" class="clearfix list">
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-paid-li">ASSET PAID</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-paid-li">ASSET PAID</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
</ul>
<ul id="assetSelectedList" class="clearfix list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can exclude `.asset-paid-li` using [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. Also use `.clone()` instead of getting HTML of elements.

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
  if (this.checked)
    $("ul#mosaic li:not(.asset-paid-li)").clone().appendTo("ul#assetSelectedList");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing1">
<ul id="mosaic" class="clearfix list">
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-paid-li">ASSET PAID</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-paid-li">ASSET PAID</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
  <li class="clearfix asset-free-li">Asset Free</li>
</ul>
<ul id="assetSelectedList" class="clearfix list"></ul>
```